# Converting file stream from http servlet response into multipartfile in Spring

Tags: java, spring, http, servlets, file-io

I am converting file stream from http servlet response got from an external API into multipartfile which will be insert into json object of the response of the API I am working on.

Due to a certain environmental issue, I can't test the external API so I don't know what exactly the content of the response is. The document of the API just said the content of response has file stream of a zip file and some metadata of the file.

The following is my pseudocode showing how I tried to convert file from http servlet response into multipartfile in a service class.

```
@Autowired
HttpServletResponse response;

externalAPIInstance.fileDownload( fileId, response);

ContentCachingResponseWrapper resWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);

byte[] byteArray = resWrapper.getContentAsByteArray();


MultipartFile result = new MockMultipartFile(filename,
                 originalFileName, "application/zip", byteArray);
```

I doubt if it would work. Especially the content of the response, it might contain something besides file stream as the API document said.

Any code example can show me how to get the conversion done?